# What is the best way for us to fetch GMails after domain wide access has been granted to our app?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace, gmail-api

We are building an App on Google Apps Marketplace which sits on top of GMail and reads customer email to provide analytics on top of it. From what I understood of the documentation:

1. When the IT admin of the customer account installs my app, my app asks for the required permissions, which is then granted to the OU/Org.
2. Now I have 2 situations:

   - a. User does a Google+ Sign In to access emails from my website
   - b. Our service works in the background to run analytics and delivers notifications/reports as and when necessary.

I'd like to be able to do this without asking each individual user again for permissions. What is the method for fetching the emails for a particular customer domain for all their users? If I follow the normal "server auth" flow, I need a refresh token for which I need access_type=offline which prompts a grant request always, and if I use service account, I'm getting a HTTP 500 "Backend Error" on my App Engine local dev server.

Before I invest time going down any path, I'd like to ascertain what the best practices are. The GMail API documentation talks about service objects but makes no mention of Service Accounts or things like AppAssertionCredentials.

Answer (score 0):

Using a service account is the correct approach, and it is possible to use one with the new Gmail API. Unfortunately the 500 error isn't very descriptive, but try re-reading the service account documentation and check that you have everything setup correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this with a service account and having the domain administrator whitelist your app in the cpanel.  It takes a little bit of work with keys to form the JWT claim set in order to request credentials for $RANDOM_USER in the domain but it's explained pretty well at:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount#formingclaimset

Once you've done that, working with the Gmail API should look the same as when you were given access directly by the user.